# Office Js detachFromList() online Word issue

Tags: ms-office, office-js

This is my code:

```
let paragraph = paragraphs.items[paragraphs.items.length - 1];
let p = paragraph.insertParagraph('', window.Word.InsertLocation.after);

if (paragraph.isListItem) {
    p.detachFromList()
    p.leftIndent = 0
}
```

It works nicely, thanks to the help from MS people watching SO issues.

However, that works on the desktop version of Word. The online version of Word does not end the bullet list when using some templates so the new content (`p`) is added as a part of the list. No error is thrown.

I've tried playing around with `paragraph.insertBreak('line')` at a few places, but I'm unsure what would be the best thing to do here in order to keep the same user experience across platforms.

Any way I can do this so it works the same both on the desktop and on the online version of Word? Tested in Chrome, used the template `General Notes` for testing bullet lists. Works fine online if bullet list is generated by user, through the Home menu, but `General Notes` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just tried the exact same code i sent you in word online, and it also works, so you should be fine...

try to apply this after you insert your paragraph at the end.

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        var  listI = context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().listItemOrNullObject;
        context.load(listI);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (listI.isNullObject) { // check out how i am validating if its null.
                    console.log("there is no list at the end")
                }
                else {
                    context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().detachFromList();
                    context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().leftIndent = 0;
                    return context.sync();
                }

            })
    })
```

Comment: Did you specifically try using the template `General Notes`? It does work fine in online word if a list is generated manually, but it doesn't work inside this template.

Comment: Edit - I've copy/pasted your code. Works fine in desktop, but doesn't work online at all. All it does is it sets left indent to 0 for the list. I can send you screenshots if needed and the exact code. And I don't see my new paragraph inserted (while it's inserted on the desktop version).

Comment: Hello I tried the code in Online and its working. Are you using One Drive for Consumer? Business? or are you using onPrem SP? please let me know. thanks!

Comment: Have you specifically tried the template `General notes`? It doesn't work in that template. It works Online per se, but not in this template. Where can I check which One Drive am I using?

Comment: are you logging in with an organization account or an MSA account (by MSA i mean hotmail, outlook.com type of accounts)

Comment: BTW i tried with the general notes template and to code snippet is working as expected.

Comment: I'm logging in with my Skype ID, actually, but I do believe it's linked to my gmail.com account. I did get the invitation from the company I'm working for, but the invitation was for my personal gmail address. Does that help? A colleague of mine (he's QA) has the same issue with General notes as I do (when using that template online).

Comment: what's the site you are logging in to?

Comment: The code above started working after we've (Juan Balmori and I) tweaked it a bit to work for my specific use case (inserting paragraphs) - without having to alter the logic of the code snippet above.